# How Can I Quickly Populate a Firestore DB?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm setting up a Firestore database and am playing around with structuring it. Is there a way to populate and change it quickly without having to add/change fields manually every single time?

Two example things I am looking to do are:

1) Populate collections with documents that have predetermined fields. Currently I have to add the fields manually every single time.

2) Edit the fields en masse for all documents within a collection (e.g. change the name of a field, delete a field entirely, add a new field)

The Firebase console doesn't seem to provide these tools, would my best bet be to write a separate app specifically for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Since such bulk uploads and bulk edits are not part of the console, you'll have to build something yourself indeed.

A good place to start would be the Cloud Firestore API, which allows [adding and updating documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) in the database.